# Openerp rule definition

Tags: odoo, definition, rule

I would like to show records only for certain users what belong to group logged with same state of user_id. Also, if user is not supplier would show all records.

This is the first part of the sentence, but i really don't know how to finish it. Thanks in advance.

```
[('state_id.id','=', user.partner_id.state_id.id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['|',(user.partner_id,'=',False),('state_id','=', user.partner_id.state_id.id)]
```

Hope it helps.